# I'm getting this error: error c2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments, but I don't understand why

Tags: c++, file, mutex, locks, rwlock

I'm having this error: error c2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments.
The thing is the function takes 0 arguments and I call 0 arguments, and I don't understand what's wrong.

```
    RWLock* rwl = new RWLock();
    std::thread t1(&RWLock::read);
```

That's the call to the function.
And this is the function:

```
    void read();
```

Does somebody know what the problem is?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

All non-static member functions have a hidden argument, that becomes the `this` pointer in the member function If you want to use a non-static member function as a thread, you have to provide this hidden argument when starting the thread:

```
std::thread t1(&RWLock::read, rwl);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure, that `read()` is not a static function. That is, you declared it as:

`void read()`

instead of:

`static void read()`

Non-static member function takes always one additional argument - implicit `this` pointer. Make `read()` static and it should work.

If `read()` cannot be static, pass an additional argument to `std::thread` - a pointer to object, that `read()` will work on. In this case it should be `rwl`:

```
RWLock* rwl = new RWLock();
std::thread t1(&RWLock::read, rwl);
```